# Possible to format the token output in antlr4?

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4, lexer

In antlr when I run the following test command to grab tokens:

```
$ grun TestLexer tokens -tokens myfile.sql
[@0,0:5='SELECT',<'SELECT'>,1:0]
[@1,7:7='1',<NUMBER>,1:7]
[@2,9:12='with',<'WITH'>,2:0]
[@3,14:20='my_data',<IDENTIFIER>,2:5]
[@4,22:23='as',<'AS'>,2:13]
[@5,25:25='(',<'('>,2:16]
[@6,27:32='select',<'SELECT'>,2:18]
[@7,34:40=''text1'',<STRING_TOKEN>,2:25]
[@8,41:42='::',<'::'>,2:32]
```

Is there a way for it to actually name or format the token, such as for the last one to have:

```
[@8,41:42='::',<'TYPECAST(::)'>,2:32]
```

As it's been declared in my TextLexer.g4 file:

```
// Cast operator, '2014-01-01'::DATE
TYPECAST
    :'::'
    ;
```

Answer (score 2):

You would need to create a new implementation of the Token interface (waviest would be to subclass `CommonToken` And override the `toString()` Method.  You’d also need to create a new `TokenFactory` to create Tokens of your type.  At that point you can write your own code to print out the tokens.  There’s not a way to override the `TokenFactory` in the `TestRig class.

There’s code to do just this in the “Tokens and Token Factories” section of [The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference](https://pragprog.com/titles/tpantlr2/the-definitive-antlr-4-reference/)

Based on the questions you’re posting, this book is going to prove well worth it’s price.